# How can you get Sinatra to properly process a JSON request that has an array in it?

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I am POST'ing to a Sinatra with javascript as follows:

```
var payload = {
  cart: [ 
    {qty: 1, product: { name: 'baseball' },
    {qty: 3, product: { name: 'soccer' } 
  ]
}

$.post("/endpoint", payload, submit)
```

From Sinatra, params yields the following:

```
{"cart" => {
  "0"=>{"qty"=>"1", "product"=> {"name"=>"baseball"} },
  "1"=>{"qty"=>"3", "product"=> {"name"=>"soccer"} }
}}
```

How can I make the params to turn out like this instead?

```
{ 
  :cart => [
    { :qty => 1, :product => { :name => "baseball" } },
    { :qty => 3, :product => { :name => "soccer" } },
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first thing you need to understand to solve this problem is that you are currently *not* sending JSON. JQuery is serializing the data as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, using the [`param()` function](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/), and is sending (it is actually sending the escaped version of this):

```
cart[0][qty]=1&cart[0][product][name]=baseball&cart[1][qty]=3&cart[1][product][name]=soccer
```

The documentation for `param()` has the following pair of notes:

> Note: Because some frameworks have limited ability to parse serialized arrays, developers should exercise caution when passing an obj argument that contains objects or arrays nested within another array.

and

> Note: Because there is no universally agreed-upon specification for param strings, it is not possible to encode complex data structures using this method in a manner that works ideally across all languages supporting such input. Use JSON format as an alternative for encoding complex data instead.

This is the issue you are facing. Sinatra tries to parse the form-urlencoded data into a Ruby data structure, but it is expecting a different format. It is using `Rack::Utils.parse_nested_query` which produces the params you are seeing from that query string.

As the jQuery docs suggest, the solution is to send the data as JSON. This will ensure the structure of the data is not mangled between the browser and the server.

The first step is to get the browser to send JSON. You can do this with the other form of the `post()` function, specifying the content type and converting the data to a JSON string:

```js
$.post({url: "/endpoint", data: JSON.stringify(payload), contentType: "application/json", success: submit});
```

By default Sinatra will ignore any request with a content type of JSON, and leave the processing to you, so the other half of the solution is to get Sinatra to parse the JSON, and optionally populate the params hash.

One way of doing this to use the Rack contrib module `PostBodyContentTypeParser`. Simply add the following to your app (you will need to install the `rack-contrib` gem first):

```ruby
require 'rack/contrib/post_body_content_type_parser'

use Rack::PostBodyContentTypeParser
```

Now any POST or PUT request that has a JSON content type will be parsed and the contents added to the params hash. However the current released version doesn’t have and way to convert the keys to symbols (there is a change in master to allow this, but it hasn’t been released yet) so it will produce something like:

```
{
  "cart"=>[
    {"qty"=>1, "product"=>{"name"=>"baseball"}},
    {"qty"=>3, "product"=>{"name"=>"soccer"}}
  ]
}
```

If you want to get symbolized keys you will have to do it “manually”. In your route you can add:

```ruby
request.body.rewind # Just in case some middleware has already read it
data = JSON.parse(request.body.read, symbolize_names: true)
```

(You could add this to a `before` filter if you wanted, just add a check that the content type actually is JSON).

This doesn’t add the data to the `params` hash, but does give you the data in the form you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

```
cart_params = {"cart" => {
  "0"=>{"qty"=>"1", "product"=> {"name"=>"baseball"} },
  "1"=>{"qty"=>"3", "product"=> {"name"=>"soccer"} }
}}

> hash = JSON.parse(cart_params.to_json, symbolize_names: true)
> hash[:cart] = hash[:cart].values
> hash
#=> {
#    :cart=>[
#            {:qty=>"1", :product=>{:name=>"baseball"}}, 
#            {:qty=>"3", :product=>{:name=>"soccer"}}
#          ]
#   }
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem a while ago and I have created the `gem` doing that (any many other things simplifying deeply nested structures iteration/mapping). Check [`Iteraptor`](https://github.com/am-kantox/iteraptor).

```
json = {"cart" => {
  "0"=>{"qty"=>"1", "product"=> {"name"=>"baseball"} },  
  "1"=>{"qty"=>"3", "product"=> {"name"=>"soccer"} }  
}}
json.aplanar.recoger(symbolize_keys: true)
#⇒ {:cart=>[
#    {:qty=>"1", :product=>{:name=>"baseball"}},
#    {:qty=>"3", :product=>{:name=>"soccer"}}]}
```

You might check the source code to see it’s not entirely trivial to achieve the desired result manually.

Comment: Thanks for this! But I'm just curious, how optimized is this Gem?

Comment: If the data comes from AJAX call it won't be a bottleneck. Feel free to examine the source if in doubt.